# all media converter

Tags: linux, software-rec

do you know something which is able to convert almost all media types?
from flv to music to wav to mp3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have a look at the FFmpeg project.

From the project description:

> "FFmpeg is a complete, cross-platform
>   solution to record, convert and stream
>   audio and video. It includes
>   libavcodec - the leading audio/video
>   codec library."

It is likely already installed on your system because a lot of media players depend on the libavcodec library.

To see the available codecs on your system, execute `ffmpeg -codecs`

- [list of codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ffmpeg#Codecs) provided by ffmpeg
- [list of video codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec#Implemented_video_codecs) provided by libavcodec
- [list of audio codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec#Implemented_audio_codecs) provided by libavcodec

Answer (score 4):

[ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) is what you are looking for.

You can read through the official [documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html).

Otherwise just search on [google](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=how+to+calculate+the+mode+with+my+calculator#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&q=ffmpeg+convert+.mp4+to+.avi&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=7b3e9e0669ddb0a1) "convert X to Y with ffmepg", where X and Y would be the formats you trying to convert between.

---

A few resources that has helped me:

[here](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs) and [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/tagged/76/ffmpeg)

Comment: `ffmpeg` is black magic. Most of the time just `ffmpeg -i input-filename output-filename` will work by itself; it figures out the formats and does the right thing automatically

Comment: unless you are very very unlucky

Comment: and then it is really really black magic :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can try [transcode](http://www.transcoding.org/) too, its a great command line application.

Answer (score 3):

Check out **Handbrake**.  I use it on linux.

Answer (score 1):

I regulary use http://www.online-convert.com/ which is an online service for conversion between all kinds of audio, video, image and document formats.